# Correct arguments for svm() function in R

Tags: r, svm, kernel-trick

I'm looking to implement a linear and non-linear SVM in R but having some confusion over which argument to use in `svm()`. For the linear SVM I want to add in the penalty $\gamma$ for soft margin. This is the `gamma =` argument, correct? How is it different from the `cost =`  or `epsilon =` argument?

Secondly, under the RBF kernel in the non-linear SVM, what is the sigma/bandwidth argument called?

Answer (score 2):

I have figured it out. For svm() the correct argument for soft margin is "cost" and the correct argument for bandwidth under the rbf kernel is implicitly defined by "gamma"